# include jquery Script inside PHP, with php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

got a strange problem here. So Im Using jquery Ui with the "Accordion-Widget".

Everything is working fine, but if i start to include a short jquery-script, everything gets messed up.

So if have a loop which updates Variables and is filling tables. After the Tables are filled, the user could change the data of the table. Depending of how the values are changed, the Heads of the Accordion has to be changed aswell.
Also the Tables are initially filled with , i would call it proposal values.

So heads also have to be changed **after** the table is filled initially.

To do this, i just created a small jquery script and put it **after the while-loop** - but inside the accordion tag - like so. The Script adds Text to the Heads and changes the css (background-color)

```
                ?>
                    <script>
                     $( function() {
                         check_entnommen(<?php echo json_encode($sess_key); ?>,<?php echo json_encode($offen); ?>);
                          });
                      </script>
                <?php
```

But if i do this, the accordion totally gets messed up, it think this is because the function-part gets also printed out.

Here i have to pictures. Pic1 accordion looks like without the part above
Pic2 accordion looks like with the part above

Pic1
[image: Pic1]
Pic2
[image: Pic2]

So why the jquery-printin part gets printed out? I think this is why the accordion getting messed up

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a few things wrong with your script.
Your syntax is wrong:

```
$(function() {
    // code
});
```

I assume you are trying to run the JavaScript function `check_entnommen()`.
Remove the code above and only do this instead:

```
?>
<script>
    check_entnommen(<?php echo json_encode($sess_key); ?>, <?php echo json_encode($offen); ?>);
</script>
<?php
```

If you are trying to run the function *after the document has loaded*, do this:

```
?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        check_entnommen(<?php echo json_encode($sess_key); ?>, <?php echo json_encode($offen); ?>);
    });
</script>
<?php
```

If it's possible that `$sess_key` or `$offen` are not numbers but strings, you need to add quotes:

```
check_entnommen('<?php echo json_encode($sess_key); ?>', '<?php echo json_encode($offen); ?>');
```

But all this would lead to a JavaScript syntax error, not to the script being displayed as plain text.

Make sure you insert the `script` tag in the right place; For example, don't insert it into another tag: `<div id="" <script></script> class="">contents</div>`
You mentioned you inserted your script *"but inside the accordion tag"* - maybe you've got a syntax error because of that. The relevant code is not included in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think what you mentioned there, adding the script inside the div, is the problem. So now Im using another approch which is working perfectly. Saving everything inside an array (all the $sess_key and $offen) now and at the end of the file, i call the script with that array and change the properties that way.